# In a view how do I get the id of a join model in rails with a has_many through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

If I have two modals joined with a has many two relationship, lets say (teams and players) and they are joined through (lineups)

Is there a way to access the join model id (lineups_id) in the view after calling something like:

```
@teams.players.each_with_index |players, index| do
  players.lineups_id
end
```

Comment: Is lineups a true entity or just an associative entity to facilitate a many to many relationship? If it is the latter, it won't have an id since it's primary key will be a composite of the two foreign keys.

Comment: yes linueps is a modal of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's no way to do this. But it can be solved fairly easily by rearranging your code a bit.

```
@team.lineups.includes(:player).each_with_index |lineup, index| do
  lineup.id
  lineup.player
end
```

The `.includes(:player)` isn't actually necessary but it will improve your performance by eager loading the players.

Comment: .includes throws and error "undefined method "includes", I'm in rails 2.3.11.  Is that a rails 3 method?   Otherwise it worked!

Comment: Yes, it is a Rails 3 method. You can use `@team.lineups.find(:all, :include=>:player).each_with_index` instead on Rails 2.3.